# The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: command-line

there is no body
there is no body

Comment: Whilst poorly phrased See https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation.

Comment: It looks like character limitation problem. You would have to use more than one echo or store the text in several variables

var1=sometext
var2=sometext
var3=sometext

echo %var1%>> blabla.txt
echo %var2%>> blabla.txt
echo %var3%>> blabla.txt

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation

Comment: Why not copy and paste it to the .txt file, you pasted it here.

Comment: why are you echoing such a long line to file instead of storing the file separately right from the beginning?

Comment: So, this long line came from you manual input by argument, or, this is some output from previous output command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [heredoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015163/ddg#1015471) instead.